# Usar otro fondo de Activity cuando la orientacion cambia

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Tengo una imagen `.png` prediseñada por mi (dibujo con el nombre de la aplicación en el medio del dibujo) 1024x768

Cuando el teléfono tiene la orientación horizontal, se ve muy bien, pero cuando cambia a la orientación vertical, la imagen (que esta como fondo de tamaño completo) se comprime y se deforma. La imagen ya no se ve tan bien.

Mi pregunta es si se puede diseñar 2 imágenes diferentes para las dos orientaciones del teléfono y que se use cada una según la orientación actual.
Para no perder la calidad de la misma.

O quizás si alguno conoce otra forma de hacer eso, toda la info es bienvenida.

Código `xml` de la `activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EntradaMainActivity">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_screen2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainImagenDescripcion"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="206dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_enter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.93" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

El elemento `imageView2`esta como `fullScreen` para ocupar toda la pantalla del teléfono.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es una `LandScape Variation`, que consiste en un `layout` especifico para cuando el dispositivo cambie de orientación `potrait` (vertical) a `landscape` (horizontal).

Esto lo puedes hacer en `app > res > layout > layout que necesites en landscape`

Vas a la vista `Design` y en la barra superior de esta vista veras un icono así:

[image: screen_rotation]

Das clic y en ese menu selecciona "`Create Landscape Variation`", y automáticamente te generara un `layout` con el mismo nombre de tu actividad pero cuando se encuentre en orientación horizontal (`landscape`) de esta manera personalizas como quieres que se vea cuando este en esta orientación. Seleccionas una imagen u otra como `background` según corresponda o desees.

Comment: @OrenDiaz cualquier problema haciendo esto por favor házmelo saber, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, voy a investigar por ese lado y probarlo.